# How can I prevent the CTRL KeyEvent from being dispatched when pressing the right ALT key (ALT Gr)?

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a key binding system for my application using key events from Swing. I am detecting the key presses using a KeyListener which I added to my Canvas.

```java
Canvas canvas = new Canvas()
frame.add(canvas);
canvas.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("KEY CODE: " + e.getKeyCode() + " KEY LOCATION: " + e.getKeyLocation());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Everything works as indented, the `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` method of the KeyListener gets called for every key pressed on the keyboard.

The Problem arises when I press the aforementioned right ALT key. It results in two consecutive KeyEvents being dispatched. One for the left CTRL key, and one for the right ALT key. As far as I know the so dispatched event for the CTRL key is indistinguishable from the KeyEvent which is dispatched when actually pressing the CTRL key.

Is there a way to prevent the CTRL event from being dispatched when pressing the right ALT key, or do I have to make the right ALT key unbindable in order to avoid confusing behaviour?

Comment: It will help tremendously if you post minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: I added the code of my KeyListener.

Comment: This appears to be a Windows problem.  By the way, you may want to use [KeyEvent.getKeyText](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyText(int))(e.getKeyCode()) in your println statement.

Comment: Oh that's very neat!

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer in:

[When i press the right alt key on my keyboard the left control gets registered pressed?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/when-i-press-the-right-alt-key-on-my-keyboard-the/0ff48ac5-8888-49db-9055-8df511bb4c4c)

> Some keyboards have al ALT key on the left, and an ALT GR key on the
> right, if you have an ALT GR key, then it is correct that pressing
> that key will trigger an even that tells the operating system that Alt
> +Ctrl was pressed, this is normal.

It should mentioned that in some Windows keyboard layouts you have not this problem and right ALT key acts as ALT only.

Comment: I was wondering if apps written in Java have this problem, so I checked Minecraft. In version 1.0 you're unable to bind right ALT as it's treated as left CTRL, in the latest version however it is possible to bind the right ALT key which makes me wonder how they achieved it. Maybe it's through some external libraries.

Comment: Don't know may [Java Keyboard Keycodes list](https://codeutility.org/applet-java-keyboard-keycodes-list-stack-overflow/) help

Comment: 18 is key code for Alt and 65406 is for Alt Graph

Comment: Yeah, but I still have the problem of the unnecessary CTRL event which I cannot filter out.